# How do I restrict access to S3 resources using get_federation_token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to use federation tokens to manage access to folders in an S3 bucket. However, in my sample code the user gets access to the entire bucket. The following spec succeeds, but I would expect it to fail based on this document:
http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1DM54S2Q7TC8U/Understanding-the-API-options-for-securely-delegating-access-to-your-AWS-account

```
describe "assumed credentials" do                                                                                  
  let(:policy) {                                                                                                   
    { 
      "Version": "2012-10-17",                                                                                     
      "Statement": [                                                                                               
         {
           "Effect":"Allow",
           "Action":"s3:ListBucket",
           "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"],
           "Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":"000/"}}
         }
      ]                                                                                                            
    }                                                                                                              

  }
  it "should allow upload with federation credentials" do
    client = Aws::STS::Client.new
    token = client.get_federation_token(                                                                           
      policy: policy.to_json,
      duration_seconds: 900,                                                                                       
      name: 'S3-User'                                                                                             
    )                                                                                                              

    s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(                                                                                    
      Aws::Credentials.new(
        token.credentials.access_key_id,
        token.credentials.secret_access_key,                                                                       
        token.credentials.session_token                                                                            
      )                                                                                                            
    )
    bucket = s3.bucket('bucket-name')
    obj = bucket.object('00a/temporary3')                                                                          
    obj.delete
    obj.put(body:'Hello World!')                                                                                   
    expect(obj.exists?).to be                                                                                      
  end                                                                                                              
end
```

I found many questions from people who are unable to give access to resources, but I seem to have the opposite problem.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a bucket policy that is granting the unexpected access?  `allow` is additive.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - according to the documentation the federation token only has access to things granted by the policy given when you create it. I do have a bucket policy, but if I take that away I can't get Allow access working here.

Comment: Whose side are you on? :)  It sounds like you are indeed seeing an interaction with the bucket policy, contrary to your expectation, right?  Bucket policies are independent of IAM policy to some extent, and can apparently allow or deny things based on only the *authentication* rather than the *authorization* IAM provides.  It might be appropriate to include your bucket policy in the question, as well as any S3-relevant IAM user/group policy for the AWS user getting the federation token.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - thanks for the help. It turned out that the ruby-sdk doesn't use the keys in Aws::Credentials.new, but instead uses the keys in a different config file.

Answer (score 1):

The ruby gem doesn't let you create resources from credentials. You need to do something like the following:

```
 client = Aws::STS::Client.new                                                                                  
 token = client.get_federation_token(                                                                           
          policy: policy.to_json,                                                                                      
          duration_seconds: 900,                                                                                       
          name: 'S3-User23'                                                                                            
        )                                                                                                              
        Aws.config.update(                                                                                             
          credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(                                                                           
            token.credentials.access_key_id,                                                                           
            token.credentials.secret_access_key,                                                                       
            token.credentials.session_token                                                                            
          )                                                                                                            

        )                                                                                                              

        s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(                                                                                    
          token.credentials                                                                                            
        )
```